# Menu árvore / collapse com três níveis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, menu, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

Estou criando uma sidebar de navegação para uma aplicação em AngularJS. A estrutura é basicamente um menu de árvore, porém cada nível possui interações diferentes (que ainda irei construir). Por exemplo, o primeiro e segundo níveis só irão mostrar e esconder o conteúdo quando clicados, com animação e tudo, enquanto terceiro, dependendo de um parâmetro, irá habilitar ou desabilitar um efeito de "collapse". Eis a estrutura do menu:

- Presidente

  - Dilma
  - Aécio
  - Marina
  - Luciana Genro
- Governador

  - Alckmin
  - Skaf
  - Padilha
- Senador
- Deputado

  - Deputado Federal

    - Tirirca
    - Russomano
    - Feliciano
  - Deputado Estadual

    - Telhada
    - Tripoli
    - Capez

Cada um destes itens pode abrir um link ou expandir o menu filho. Por exemplo, ao clicar em "Senador" iria para um link com a composição do senado, enquanto os outros itens iriam expandir a lista para um outro menu lateral e os elementos filhos desta lista teriam o efeito de "collapse", ao selecionar um, esconder o outro.

Isto foi o que consegui desenvolver até agora: http://jsfiddle.net/mata9a1z/

```
<leftnav pins="true" collapsable="true" labels="true"></leftnav>
```

Gostaria de passar o parâmetro `labels` para habilitar ícones no primeiro nível, o parâmetro `pins` para o segundo nível e `collapsable` para o terceiro nível. Isso é possível?

As funções `select()` e `isSelected()` funcionam, por que `collapse()`, `isCollapsed()` e `foo()` não funcionam no terceiro nível? Eu tive que usar o atributo `require: '^leftnav'` nas diretivas porque senão seriam criadas instâncias diferentes de controllers para cada item do menu, e dessa forma quando selecionasse uma opção, não esconderia as outras. Existe outra forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível atingir o resultado desejado através de diretivas, visto que é possível haver recursão dentro de diretivas, utilizando-se do [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), que permite que uma diretiva tenha diretivas em seu template.

**seu módulo**

```
angular
  .module('MenuRecursivo', [])
  .directive('candidatos', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        // diz para o Angular criar um novo
        // escopo para a candidatos usando
        // o mesmo nome (candidatos)
        candidatos: '='
      },

      // a diretiva filha `candidato` é usada para tornar possível a recursão
      // note o ng-repeat iterando sobre a `candidatos`
      template: '<ul><candidato ng-repeat=\'candidato in candidatos\' candidato=\'candidato\'></candidato></ul>'
    };
  })
  .directive('candidato', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        // novamente, diz para o Angular
        // criar um escopo separado com o mesmo nome
        candidato: '='
      },

      // propriedade que será usada no li,
      // que pode variar conforme a necessidade.
      // aqui seria possível até criar uma nova diretiva para
      // cuidar da exibição, como inserir o texto em um <a>
      // ou apenas exibir algum dado do item
      template: '<li>{{candidato.cargo || candidato.name}}</li>',

      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        // Prepara o template dos subitens
        var subItems = '<candidatos candidatos=\'candidato.candidatos\'></candidatos>';

        // Identifica se o template deve ser compilado
        // caso este item tenha filhos ou atenda o critério
        // que define que o item tem filhos
        if (angular.isArray(scope.candidato.candidatos)) {
          // compila o template
          $compile(subItems)(scope, function (cloned, scope)   {
            // adiciona o template ao elemento atual,
            // ou seja, neste caso, o <li>
            element.append(cloned);
          });
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    // suposta estrutura
    $scope.items = [
      {
        cargo: 'Presidente',
        candidatos: [
          { name: 'Dilma' },
          { name: 'Aécio' },
          { name: 'Marina' },
          { name: 'Luciana Genro' }
        ]
      },
      {
        cargo: 'Governador',
        candidatos: [
          { name: 'Alckmin' },
          { name: 'Skaf' },
          { name: 'Padilha' }
        ]
      },
      {
        cargo: 'Senador'
      },
      {
        cargo: 'Deputado',
        candidatos: [
          {
            cargo: 'Deputado Federal',
            candidatos: [
              { name: 'Tirirca' },
              { name: 'Russomano' },
              { name: 'Feliciano' }
            ]
          },
          {
            cargo: 'Deputado Estadual',
            candidatos: [
              { name: 'Telhada' },
              { name: 'Tripoli' },
              { name: 'Capez' }
            ]
          },
          {
            cargo: 'Exemplo de 4 niveis',
            candidatos: [
              {
                cargo: 'Deputado Estadual',
                candidatos: [
                  { name: 'Telhada' },
                  { name: 'Tripoli' },
                  { name: 'Capez' }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  });
```

**html**

```
<html ng-app="MenuRecursivo">
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <candidatos candidatos='items'></candidatos>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Plnkr funcionando: http://plnkr.co/edit/D8MZUu6OAzAk1TAMnhwf

O importante é se atentar no seguinte trecho:

```
// ...
if (/* condição necessária para se executar a recursão */) {
  // compila o template
  $compile(subItems)(scope, function (cloned, scope)   {
    // adiciona o template ao elemento atual,
    // ou seja, neste caso, o <li>
    element.append(cloned);
  });
}
// ...
```

Pois este é o trecho que realiza a recursão de templates. O `subItems` seria o template para a lista filha. Acho que fica mais claro olhando no plunkr.

Creio que a partir daqui consiga adaptar conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado! De quando fiz a pergunta até agora este menu passou por muitas modificações, já havia conseguido fazê-lo funcionar mas sem utilizar o $compile. Vou tentar refatorá-lo agora usando este método.